# How do I execute a program on a custom circuit board using ARM processor?

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I'm trying to build a custom board to use LED or LCD screens using one of the ARM processors and PCB( I'm buying separate parts and soldering them on a PCB ).
I wonder how to execute a program on that board.

Do I just write a C program on my PC, compile, and upload the binary file to the board?
Or is there any other necessary program or code to execute a C program on custom ARM board?

I hope someone could show me some directions and examples. I'm lost.

Comment: Solder on a JTAG debugger port.  Note that SO is a Q&A site, and 'teach me to develop embedded systems' is way, way too broad:(

Comment: 'Teach me' was bit off the track with my intention. I edited that phrase. Thx

Comment: Could you give more information about the specific processor? Did you design the PCB? Can it be changed?

Comment: Number one you are not ready to build a pcb.  Start by buying an eval board. If you are building a pcb one would assume this is a microcontroller unless you have BGA capabilities (yes not all full sized linux capable parts are BGA I understand that).  There are countless boards like the NUCLEO-F031K6 for about $10 just about anywhere.

Comment: The NUCLEO and others from other brands defer the problem of figuring out how to download your program into the flash as they show up as a thumb drive and you simply copy the .bin file over and another MCU on the board takes care of the hard part.

Comment: Using one of these boards you learn the software side of this which there are an endless supply of examples and personal styles of how to do this.  As well as many traps that will cause you to fail, baremetal programming is great because of the freedom but not so great because of the potential to fail and difficulty in debugging.

Comment: Then maybe you get one like the NUCLEO-F401RE that has a noticable debug header on the top of the board, with that header and openocd or other tools you can use that to gain SWD access to the cortex-m core on ST parts as well as other non ST brands.  With any of these boards you can learn to use the SWD interface to learn to program the parts, or on some of them you can learn to use the serial bootloader built into the part that you can use to program them.

Comment: All of this of course is in the documentation you should have read before starting anything.  Then you can go to mouser or digikey find a part you think you can solder make or buy a breakout board, and so on.  Literally just finished soldering a couple of breakout boards myself.  Then start with blinking leds and work your way up to other things, even with the eval/dev boards you can wire up an LCD or LED display and play with it without making a pcb.

Comment: what specific chip are you thinking of using?

Comment: I'm planning to build an electric bike using STM32 series to monitor the speed and the battery. There is nothing settled. I'm using STM because I started studying embedded system with that.

Comment: ARM don't make processors.  What ARM based device are you intending to use? STM32 is not "specific" - there are literally hundreds of  STM32 variants.  Add the information to the question rather than in comments.  Most ARM parts are SMT devices - do you have the necessary tools and skills to put such a part down?  It will most likely be cheaper and more reliable for low volumes to buy a development board - e.g. ST Nucleo boards.  Either way the answer is through either JTAG/SWD or through the mask ROM bootloader.  If you are developing code, you'll want to use the JTAG/SWD debug port.

Comment: An ARM part might be overkill for that task BTW.  PIC and AVR parts are available in DIP packages more appropriate to DIY boards and have more than enough computational capability for speed and battery monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Massively broad question.  Yes you need a toolchain that can build programs for the arm processor.  Which generally means a cross compiler, good news is that gcc and clang/llvm are free and are capable of the job, but its not that easy.  Find a sandbox (someone, like the chip vendor (arm is not the chip vendor they simply made some IP that the chip vendor bought and put in their part), will have a development environment and libraries and examples) and learn from that.

And you need tools in order to get the firmware downloaded into the part.  Software and hardware tools.

Start with an eval/dev/hobby board first.  They are often $20 or less, there are many in the $10 range, enough to keep you busy for a long time.  You can wire up displays to these boards long before it is time to start thinking about making your own PCB.